# Item's page in a REST app: 200 OK or redirect?

Tags: rest, pagination

I am considering implementing a jump to item's page feature in a REST app, much like StackOverflow's does with questions with multiple answer pages. If you ask for a URL like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-books/1215215, it will jump to the question's page containing the specific answer (page 4 for this specific case as of this writing). Notice that the client *does not*  request an specific page by number, it requests a page that contains an item of interest and the server needs to resolve the page. In StackOverflow, this is used to get from a user's profile page to the user's answer in context, for example.

I would like to do that within my app, but I can't get to a final (RESTful) design. I've considered the answers to [question 776448](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776448/pagination-in-a-rest-web-application) and chose to go with the query strings only solution for the base case. But should the app respond a query to an item's page with a 200 response (like StackOverflow does) containing the page with the item, or should it respond with a 302 redirect to the query string version URL? StackOverflow went with the first solution, but which solution do you find more RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of a 302 response because it describes exactly the situation: the requested resource resides temporarily at this location (e.g., /.../list-of-books?page=4). This one boils down to personal preference though; there's no restriction on what your URLs look like.

Comment: The main problem I see with a 302 redirect is that the item may no longer be on that page when the second request hits the server (other items may be added or removed).

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. I like to be pragmatic about decisions like this. If option one will always work as expected and option two won't, ditch the questions around semantics and go with option one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, you are looking to implement a fragment identifier.

e.g.

```
/page/232#Item-2323
```

The resource you are accessing is `/page232` and you want the client to position the UI to be looking at `Item-2323`.  The server ignores everything after the # character.

Comment: I think I missphrased the question. It really wasn't about UI positioning, but how should a REST service respond to a request for a page in a paginated collection resource such that the page includes an specific item. I've changed the question example URL to try to make it more clear.