# Is it supposed to be OK to use parameter within URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

This url has parameter(:sort) in its url.  I'm sure it's against the convetion of RoR.

`http://example.com/shops?sort=updated`

Then how can I make it RESTful?

Creating new action called 'sort_update' in shops_controller.rb?
and make use access to
`http://example.com/shops/sort_update/`?

Comment: _I'm sure it's against the convetion of RoR._ Why using query string isn't RESTful ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776448/pagination-in-a-rest-web-application for some answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would add a manual route to my routes file

```
match 'shops/by_:sort', :to => 'shops#index'
```

Make sure you add this above

```
resources :shops
```

That way, an url like `/shops/by_updated` will be routed to the index action but the parameter `sort` will additionally have the value 'updated'.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think following RESTful will be good attitude to Google SEO?

Comment: I do think that it'll work better than the query string alternative.

Comment: !!! Thanks a lot what if you had more than 2 parameters??? like params[:sort] and params[:genre]???

Comment: Well nothing keeps you from `match 'shops/by_:sort/:genre'`. You can add as many as you want. I can't tell you though how google looks at an url with 15 parameters incorporated.

Comment: Thanks!! but what if the parameter was empty? If I made `match 'shops/by_:sort/:genre/:area` and what if :genre was empty??? It will be `shops/by_updated//california` Isn't it strange?