# How to add dynamic filter by fields (comma separated) , sorting , pagination in rest api?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-editor

Below is the simple code block of the rest API with get method.

right now I have added limit parameters but I want to add **Pagination** , **result per page** , **SortByFields** , **SortBy *(asc or desc)** , **filter (by multiple fields)**

```
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
     description: Returns all pets
     produces:
     - application/json
     parameters:
     - name: limit
       in: query
       description: SET LIMIT OF THE RESULT
       type: integer
       format: int32
       required: false
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack have published an [specification](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/pagination_filter_sort.html) that

> serves to provide guidance on how to handle the pagination of large
>   result sets and the best ways to provide filtering and sorting
>   capabilities in a project’s public REST API.

If using the swagger-editor, The included example twitter.yaml has some basic filtering and pagination.

See also [Pagination in a REST web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776448/pagination-in-a-rest-web-application?rq=1)

[Spring Data REST - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.query-method-resource) also explains these concepts well in Chapter 6, Paging and Sorting.